# cache or reuse cartopy features

Tags: python, caching, cartopy

I'm using Cartopy to display the GSHHSFeature coastlines in multiple Matplotlib subplots and overlay different data on them.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import numpy as np

xss = np.linspace(-21, 36, 36)
extent = [-21, 36, 33, 64]  # west,east,south,north
rows=3
cols=2

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=rows, ncols=cols, figsize=(13, 15), 
                       subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.PlateCarree()})

for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        ax[i][j].set_extent(extent)
        ax[i][j].add_feature(cfeature.GSHHSFeature(scale="intermediate", edgecolor="black", facecolor="#bca89f"))

        # Plot individual data sets on subplots
        ax[i][j].plot(xss, np.random.uniform(low=33, high=64, size=(len(xss),)), color='cyan', zorder=20, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), linewidth=2)
        
        # Write map title
        ax[i][j].set_title("Row:"+str(i)+", Col:"+str(j))

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Drawing the coastlines is a time consuming operation, particularly when using a ‘full’ dataset scale. Since the basemap is the same in each subplot, I was looking for ways to create it only once and reuse it in the loop.

Is there a way I can either cache the feature or even the entire subplot axis and define functions like `ax[i][j].plot_my_basemap(map_ax)` or `ax[i][j] = copy_axis_from(map_ax)`?

```
# Create a plot axes of choice
map_ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
map_ax.set_extent(extentd)
# Request and process the basemap features
map_ax.add_feature(cfeature.GSHHSFeature(scale="intermediate", edgecolor="black", facecolor="#bca89f"))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=2, figsize=(13, 15), 
                       subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.PlateCarree()})

for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        ax[i][j].plot_my_basemap(map_ax)

        # Plot individual data sets on subplots
        ax[i][j].plot(xss, np.random.uniform(low=33, high=64, size=(len(xss),)), color='cyan', zorder=20, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), linewidth=2)
        
        # Write map title
        ax[i][j].set_title("Row:"+str(i)+", Col:"+str(j))

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77412404/saving-cartopy-map-images-for-use-in-future-plots) (from which I adapted my example) shows how to do it with Google tiled images, but this approach doesn't work in my case because the coastlines are not image objects, but cartopy.mpl.feature_artist.FeatureArtist.

I also tried to reuse directly map_ax, change its properties and assign it to the subplots, but this doesn't work in matplotlib:

```
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        props = ax[i][j].properties()
        props = dict((k, props[k]) for k in ["position", "subplotspec"])
        ax[i][j] = map_ax.update(props)

        # Plot individual data sets on subplots
        ax[i][j].plot(xss, np.random.uniform(low=33, high=64, size=(len(xss),)), color='cyan', zorder=20, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), linewidth=2)
        
        # Write map title
        ax[i][j].set_title("Row:"+str(i)+", Col:"+str(j))
```

I was hoping to be able to define and reuse something like Basemap objects https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues/354 (but I don't want to use Basemap because it's going to be substituted by Cartopy and it has already compatibility issues with Matplotlib 3.8)

Comment: I have added a Cartopy solution below, but you may also like to know that a new Basemap release that works with Matplotlib 3.8 is expected in the next couple of days https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues/594#issuecomment-1880169476

Comment: Tip: if you add the [python] tag to your question, then you get syntax highlighting on your code snippets, which will make them a little easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work if you are using `plt.show()` each time but if you are saving each image you can just update the y-data on the `Line2D` object that is created by `ax.plot`.

I used the standard `coastlines` call just to speed things up for this example.  I also removed `tight_layout` as it was moving the subplots for each iteration.  Using `layout='compressed'` in the figure creation gave me more consistent layouts.

Note that the artists returned by most (all?) matplotlib plotting methods have some sort of `set_data` method, so this should be generalisable if your real example is using something other than `plot`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import numpy as np

xss = np.linspace(-21, 36, 36)
extent = [-21, 36, 33, 64]  # west,east,south,north

nrows = 3
ncols = 2


fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=nrows, ncols=ncols, figsize=(13, 15), 
                       subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.PlateCarree()},
                       layout='compressed')


for n in range(3):
    for i in range(nrows):
        for j in range(ncols):
            if n == 0:
                # Set up maps and plot first data. 
                ax[i][j].set_extent(extent)
                ax[i][j].coastlines()
                
                # Plot individual data sets on subplots
                ax[i][j].plot(xss, np.random.uniform(low=33, high=64, size=(len(xss),)), color='cyan', zorder=20, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), linewidth=2)
            
            else:
                # Replace line y-data.
                ax[i][j].get_lines()[0].set_ydata(np.random.uniform(low=33, high=64, size=(len(xss),)))
            
            # Write map title
            ax[i][j].set_title("Row:"+str(i)+", Col:"+str(j))

    plt.savefig(f'myplot{n}.png')
```

Comment: Thanks for your example! Unfortunately this is not yet solving my issue. This code still calls the coastlines 6 times (one for each subplot). What I'm trying to achieve is to generate the coastlines only once, e.g. for the first subplot ax[0][0], and then reuse it in the next five subplots.